# website of interactive audio podcast, "on-demand"

Tags: audio, streaming, interactive, wowza

what is the best way to make podcasts available on a website, in a more interactive way possible.

I have to use Wowza? how does it work? how to create a stream to the user's liking of several hundred files already recorded, these podcasts are episodes of a radio show ...

is there a way to 'tag' and listen to the audio at will?

I can not be more specific in my question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Wowza allows on-demand streaming and live streaming.
+ you can use server-side playlists, i mean you can create live feed from already recorded files, so that will behave like TV.

IMO Wowza should be ok for your project, however some consultant/developer will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Wowza should work well for what you are trying to do.  I would contact their team to have them help tell you specifically what you will need.

Comment: Hi there & welcome, new user. You have not really answered the questions, so in this case you normally post a comment on the question rather than posting an answer. Thank you for keeping Stack Overflow clean!